# Power BI: excluding a visual from a slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have two different visuals on the same page of a Power BI doc, but one is being affected by the page slicer while the other one isn't. I have other visuals on the same tab that I want to slice by the slicer, so I want to select which visuals are affected by the page-level slicer.

[Visual that isn't being affected by slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX7Cs.png)

[Visual that IS being affected by slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqRhX.png)

I followed the tab for "Control which page visuals are affected by slicers" on this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers#:%7E:text=Use%20visual%20interactions%20to%20keep%20slicer%20selections%20from,under%20Visual%20Tools%2C%20and%20then%20select%20Edit%20interactions.) but it's not working. I want the second visual series to look like the first, how do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the Power BI Desktop menu, select the Format menu under Visual Tools, and then select Edit interactions.

You need to have the slicer selected. Only then you see the according Filter on/off symbols next to the visuals. When the visuals are close to each other it's sometimes hard to tell which filter switch belongs to which visual. Try pulling them temporarily apart.

Comment: I realized that the slicer itself needed to be selected, rather than selecting the visual I wanted unfiltered. It worked!